# R input file arabic?

Tags: r, input, arabic

I am writing a program that reads arabic text from a text file in R, whenever i read the file i get the following errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In read.table("C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\Desktop\\arabic.txt", sep = "\n",  :
invalid input found on input connection 'C:\Users\Mustafa\Desktop\arabic.txt'
2: In read.table("C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\Desktop\\arabic.txt", sep = "\n",  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\Mustafa\Desktop\arabic.txt'


File<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Mustafa\\Desktop\\arabic.txt",sep="    \n",col.names="ar",fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

I have no idea where error is , the environment i am using is windows, on mac os it works file, however i must run it on windows! any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It means there is a non UTF-8 character in your data. Try loading in specified rows to see if you can narrow down where it could be. Alternatively, sometimes you can just open it in excel, convert to csv and the problem goes away. `,` and `'` characters are what I generally find to be the culprits when I work in other languages.

Comment: I will try your approach adding them line by line, i have tried setting system locale and it fixed it i can read arabic character, i will also try the excel approach, many thanks

Comment: If it works on macos but not windows, good chance the end-of-line character is not what windows "likes." It's an age-old problem of <CR> vs <CR>-<LF> vs <LF> .  You might be able to open the file in WordPad, do a SaveAs (text-only) and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your file?

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that your file does not end with `EOL` (end-of-line character) e.g. `\n` or `\r\n`.

This is sort of a `warning` that your file might not be completed. It seems that on MAC it is ignored, but in windows it is considered an error.

The solution is easy, just add a new line at the end of your file, save it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Arabic")
```